# Getting unexpected data from central domain inside the tenants domain in Stancl/ Laravel Tenancy

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, multi-tenant

I am using the Stancl/TenancyforLaravel tenancy system.

I have created a model and migration called PaymentSettings for both tenants and central domain users.

For central Users = `app\Models\System\Admin\PaymentSettings.php`

For tenants users = `app\Models\Tenant\Admin\PaymentSettings.php`

I have added the crud operation which is running absolutely fine.
I am facing the challenge while setting up the stripe API on boot, in the service provider.
When I am fetching the settings data from the database

File:  `app\Providers\TenancyServiceProvider.php`

```
namespace App\Providers;
use App\Models\System\Admin\SmtpSettings as AdminSmtpSettings;
use App\Models\Tenant\Admin\AdvanceSettings;
use App\Models\Tenant\Admin\GeneralSettings;
use App\Models\Tenant\Admin\PaymentSettings;
use App\Models\Tenant\Admin\SmtpSettings;
 ...

public function boot()
    {
        $this->bootEvents();
        $this->mapRoutes();        
        $this->makeTenancyMiddlewareHighestPriority();
        $this->viewResource();
    }
 ....
   protected function viewResource(){
        View::composer('*', function ($view) {
            $this->setConfigData();
            if(Schema::hasTable('general_settings')){
                $generalSettings = GeneralSettings::findOrFail(1);
                $advanceSettings = AdvanceSettings::findOrFail(1);
                $view->with([
                        'tenant_general' => $generalSettings,
                        'tenant_advance' => $advanceSettings,
                ]);
            }
        });
    }
 protected function setConfigData()
    {

        // When tenancy exists fetch the data from the tenants data;
        $smtpTableExists = Schema::hasTable('smtp_settings');
        $smtpSettings = null;
        if(tenancy()->tenant){
            if($smtpTableExists){  $smtpSettings = SmtpSettings::findOrFail(1); }
           
            // Stripe Payment settings
            $paymentTableExists = Schema::hasTable('payment_settings');
            if($paymentTableExists){
                $paymentSettings = PaymentSettings::findOrFail(1);
                // return dd($paymentSettings->key);
                if($paymentSettings && $paymentSettings->method === 'Stripe'){
                    Config::set('services.stripe.key', $paymentSettings->key);
                    Config::set('services.stripe.secret', $paymentSettings->secret);
                    Config::set('services.stripe.webhook_secret', $paymentSettings->webhook_secret);
                    Stripe::setApiKey($paymentSettings->key);
                }
            }
        } // ends tenants config
        else { // fetch data from the central domain
            if($smtpTableExists){  $smtpSettings = AdminSmtpSettings::findOrFail(1); }
        }

        // set configs
        if($smtpSettings){
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', $smtpSettings->host);
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', $smtpSettings->port);
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.encryption', $smtpSettings->encryption);
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', $smtpSettings->username);
            Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', $smtpSettings->password);
            Config::set('mail.from.address', $smtpSettings->from_address);
            Config::set('mail.from.name', $smtpSettings->from_name);
        }

    }
....
```

As I have already set up the API key, I should get this inside the controllers, but is  not so,
I am getting the value `null`  inside the other controllers when I am calling `Stripe::getApiKey()`

I thought maybe the boot file is not running properly, to  I tried to manually write this inside the controllers' constructor inside the tenant's domain as

```
use App\Models\Tenant\Admin\PaymentSettings;

public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $paymentSettings = PaymentSettings::findOrFail(1);
        Stripe::setApiKey($paymentSettings->key);
       return dd(Stripe::getApiKey()); // showing the incorrect value from the central domain
   }
```

But the problem did not end here,
The value that I am getting is the value from the Central domain not the tenant domain inside the controllers.
BUT when I am writing a similar thing inside any other method in the tenant's controller, it's giving the correct value.

```
use App\Models\Tenant\Admin\PaymentSettings;

public function index()
    {
         // return dd(Stripe::getApiKey()); // showing the incorrect correct value from central domain

        $paymentSettings = PaymentSettings::findOrFail(1);
        Stripe::setApiKey($paymentSettings->key);

          return dd(Stripe::getApiKey()); // showing the correct value

        return view(someviewfilename);
   }
```

Expected behavior

I want to fetch the tenant's database data when I am on the tenant's domain, not the central domain DB data.

Your setup

- Laravel version: ^7.0
- stancl/tenancy version: ^3.2
- Storage driver: DB
- laravel/cashier: ^12.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the creator.
https://github.com/stancl/tenancy/issues/558

> Think about how the Laravel request lifecycle works.
>
> Here you're defining some middleware specifics: [image]
>
> And on the next line, you expect the middleware to be already
> executed? Of course it's not, Laravel first executes service providers
> and controller constructors, and only then does it know what
> middleware to use.